# Set default appsettings in Kudu Azure Websites deployment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu

Is it possible to set a default appsettings keys/values in AzureWebsites in deployment script?

I know that is possible in web.config, but I want to be set in AzureWebsites configuration tab dynamically
eg.

```
key:dbname value:%Websitename%-db

key:deploymentTime value=%time%
```

Comment: How does this appSettings get used later?  Is it just for diagnostics?

Answer (score 2):

You can use applicationHost.xdt to add app settings dynamically as described here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples

Where you put a `applicationHost.xdt` file under the `d:\home\site' directory.

The content of this file would be:

`<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="Insert" >
         <environmentVariables>
            <add name="appsetting_{SETTING NAME}" value="{SETTING VALUE}" />
         </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>`

> NOTE: One caveat is that after putting this file you need to restart the site in order for it to take effect.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the deployment of the `applicationHost.xdt` file?

Comment: You can use a custom deployment script: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/